# Sencha touch: nested list with multiple root properties

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm trying to display the JSON structure shown below in a nested list. Each category has a name and consists of subcategories and leafs.

```
{
    name: 'root',
    categories: [
        {
            name: 'Category 1',
            categories: [
                {
                    name: 'Category 1.1',
                    leafs: [
                        { name: 'Leaf 1.1.1', leaf: true },
                        { name: 'Leaf 1.1.2', leaf: true }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            leafs: [
                { name: 'Leaf 1.1', leaf: true },
                { name: 'Leaf 1.2', leaf: true }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Category 2',
            leafs: [
                { name: 'Leaf 2.1', leaf: true },
                { name: 'Leaf 2.2', leaf: true }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The data model is the following:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Leaf', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
        ]
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.Category', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    //requires: ['MyApp.model.Leaf'],

    config: {
        fields: [
            'id', 'name'
        ],
        hasMany: [
            {
                model: 'MyApp.model.Category',
                name: 'categories',
                associationKey: 'categories'
            },
            {
                model: 'MyApp.model.Leaf',
                name: 'statistics',
                associationKey: 'leafs'
            }
        ],

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'http://192.168.178.103?data',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'categories'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the nested list:

```
{
    xtype: 'nestedlist',
    title: 'Kategorien',
    displayField: 'name',
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        model: 'MyApp.model.Category'
    })
}
```

The problem is: The nested list shows me all categories und their child categories correctly, but I'm not able to get the leafs displayed. I think the reason is that the identifier of the leaf array is named 'leafs' and therefor is not recognized but i can only give one root property identifier.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.